# How do I identify an ERC-1967 contract?

Tags: ethers.js, proxy-contracts

I understand both how to read the `_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT` and how to get the implementation address of a proxy, provided I *know* the contract is a proxy.

What I'm wondering is: how do I determine *if* any given contract is an ERC-1967 provided just the contract address and the ABI?

For example, the [Supepe contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6339e5e072086621540d0362c4e3cea0d643e114#code) is a transparent proxy and doesn't have an `implementation(address)` function. Without explicitly knowing that it is a transparent proxy, how would I determine that it is? I don't want to assume just because it has an `Upgraded` event that it's a proxy, since other contracts could have the same event without being a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERC-1967 only standardizes storage slots. The ABI could be empty. You can read the implementation storage slot for that address, and if it has a non-zero value you can assume it's a proxy for most purposes.